# Remove() doesn't work with many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I am trying to remove an object from a collection in entity framework, but unfortunately my code is failing. I would be grateful if you could have a look and let me know if you can figure out what I'm doing wrong. My objects are as follows:

- Person <-> Badge (many-to-many relationship)
- Badge <-> BadgeRequirement (one-to-many relationship)
- Person contains an **ICollection** of Badges
- Badge contains an **ICollection** of Person
- BadgeRequirement contains a Badge **Foreign Key**

Adding and editing entries works absolutely fine.

However, when I try to remove a Badge from a Person using the code below, it doesn't work:

```
Postback event handler on example.aspx
****The person object has been loaded as part of the load event on the page****

Badge badge = BadgeHelper.getBadge(badgeID);
if (command == "Delete")
{
 PersonHelper.removeBadgeFromPerson(badge, person);
 }

 Delete method on PersonHelper class (wrapper for all processing)

 person.Badges.Remove(badge);
 DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The Remove(badge) returns false and I cannot profile this as I am using SQL Compact 4.0

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you debug your code and check that `Badges` collection on the `person` contains the badge you are trying to remove? Does it contain any badge?

Comment: Hi Ladislav, I can verify that the person object contains a fully loaded Badges collection. In my "Get" query, i use the from p in person.Include("Badges") to ensure that the collection is loaded and passed around accordingly. However, when I try to remove the badge in question from the collection, no deletion is perform. Instead the remove(badge) returns false. Not sure if this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was actually resolved in one of the MSDN forums. The full details can be found on the link [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4b3998a0-6b6a-40b9-8c4f-e8e04f39895b)

However, as a summary, to use the Remove() method, both collections in the many to many relationship need to be loaded before any changes take place. The code sample is attached below:

```
class Program  {
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var context= new MyContext())
  {
    var post1 = context.Posts.Find(3);
    var tag1 = context.Tags.Find(2);
    context.Entry(post1).Collection("Tags").Load();
    post1.Tags.Remove(tag1);        
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
}
public class Post
{
  public int PostId { get; set; }
  public string PostContext { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
  public int TagId { get; set; }
  public string TagContext { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I hope that this helps somebody else with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, I ended up just executing a raw SQL command against the join table:

```
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [dbo].[Badges_Persons] WHERE Badge_Id=5000 AND Person_Id=1000");
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```